# Adaptation as in a 'Movie adaptation'

Tags: english-to-japanese

If I want to say something like:

This movie was adapted from a novel

> この映画は小説から適応されました。

Is this the right way to say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 適応 only works with another meaning of adapt/adaptation, one that has to do with the environment, biology, and people.

For creative works:

> この映画はその小説を原作{げんさく}とした作品だ

> これはその小説を原案{げんあん}にした映画だ

> 小説を脚色{きゃくしょく}した映画だ

Comment: Is 脚色 used enough to be worth a mention? I know the Oscar for best adapted screenplay is called 脚色賞.

Comment: @Leebo Ooh that's a good word. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The 英和辞典 that's part of Apple's "Dictionary" app glosses "adaptation" in this sense as 「«…の/…用の» 改作(物), 脚色作品」, and also includes 「その小説の映画化作品」as a translation of "a movie adaptation of the novel." I have no idea how common these alternatives are, but they have the advantage of being a bit more compact than what you have proposed.

Comment: @Nanigashi I like them too, and I think they deserve a separate answer. I just offered what I commonly see/hear in similar contexts.

Comment: I think many people would not understand this usage of 脚色する easily. It’s normally only used in another meaning (to exaggerate or color something).

Comment: Fun fact: choosing between 原案 or 原作 is sometimes literally a million dollar question. Kinda like how you may dodge a bullet by saying "This song is inspired by..." instead of "This song is based on..."

Answer (score 3):

How about using 「もと(元)」, as in...

> これは、小説をもとにした映画です。
> この映画は、小説をもとにしています。

Or 「映画化」, as @Nanigashi suggested:

> これは、小説を映画化したものです。

I think using 原作 (in @Eddie's post) is good, too. I think you can also say it like this:

> これは、小説を原作にした映画です。
> この映画は、小説が原作となっています。